# Removing myself from a shared Google Drive to free up space on my Android

Tags: google-drive

I was given access to a shared drive with a huge library of videos, documents, etc., and installed it on my Android. I no longer need access and it is using a huge amount of space.

How do I remove the drive from my phone, the data it's taking up on my drive but leave the files intact for others?

Comment: AFAIK, the Google Drive app doesn't store shared files automatically on the device unless they're marked for "Offline" or downloaded manually.

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew mentioned, the files are not normally stored on your device.  Unless you have marked them offline, in which case uncheck each one.

A faster and more certain method is follows (steps will differ slightly from model to model)

1. Go to Settings
2. Select Apps
3. Select Google Drive
4. Select Storage
5. You can see how much space it uses.
6. Definitely, **Clear Cache**
7. If the value for **Data** is high then **Clear Data** as well.